# iOS create local notification when app exit with 10 days

Tags: ios, localnotification

I am create a local notification with 10 days and at 15:30 when app exit. Here is a code:

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    float day = 10;
    NSDate *newDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*day];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: newDate];

    [componentsForFireDate setHour: 15];
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:30];
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0];
    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

When I try change date & time in the my phone to the next day (now + 1), It's still show notification, next day, still show. I want local notification show each 10 days when app exit. Any suggests to fix this problems ?

Comment: localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay try this

Comment: @salmancs43: still show notification when I increase to the next day, not 10 days, another suggests ?

Comment: You want to fire the notification after 10 days when app exit?

Comment: I have setup to fire the notification after 10 days when app exit, but incorrectly, It's still show notification each 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code: your app open after 10 day notification fire and other 1 day fire.

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate: [NSDate date]];
componentsForFireDate.day = componentsForFireDate.day + 10;
[componentsForFireDate setHour: 15];
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:30];
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0];
NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@",fireDateOfNotification);
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
localNotification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

hope this code help you.

Comment: Will `componentsForFireDate.day += 10` cope with wrapping?

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Comment: componentsForFireDate.day += 10 and my both are same. your choice how to write.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't my point.  Will it cope with wrapping?  For example what happens when `.day = 25` and `+= 10` makes it `35`?

Comment: Thanks !!! Its work on the first times. After 10 days, a notification appear. But, user clear it, and the next day, notification still show. Any help ?

Comment: app doesn't open that after 10 day notification fire and continue notification fire next day up to app doesn't open and app open that start than after 10 day in loop.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the time in your system, please check the simulator time also. initially it not updated.

In simulator settings, General->language & region-> Advanced-> Automatica switch will be on mode. select off and on. then you simulator time will also change

Comment: Thanks, I will try